# Why do some Linux programs specify long form and shorthand arguments?

Tags: linux, command-line, command-line-arguments

Whenever I look through documentation and man-pages, I notice that most linux programs have 2 types of arguments, and this is a genuine interest I have in finding out...

- One seems to be the full argument name (long form).
- And one seems to be a shorthand.

Take `grep` for example. If i run `grep --help`  **DISCLAIMER**: This is not a question about `grep` in particular. I've seen this in many other tools.

```
Regexp selection and interpretation:
  -E, --extended-regexp     PATTERN is an extended regular expression
  -F, --fixed-strings       PATTERN is a set of newline-separated strings
  -G, --basic-regexp        PATTERN is a basic regular expression
  -P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
  -e, --regexp=PATTERN      use PATTERN as a regular expression
  -f, --file=FILE           obtain PATTERN from FILE
  -i, --ignore-case         ignore case distinctions
  -w, --word-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole words
  -x, --line-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole lines
  -z, --null-data           a data line ends in 0 byte, not newline
```

One can see that there are 2 types of arguments. a shorthand, and the full argument name.

Another thing to note, is if you specify the shorthand of these arguments, they are separated by a space, but when using the full argument, it seems to be separated by the `=` sign. e.g: `grep --file=FILE` vs `grep -f FILE`

1. What is the purpose of having 2 different types of arguments that do the same thing?
2. Are you able to use `grep --file FILE` instead of `grep --file=FILE`?
3. To question 2, if your answer is "because that is how that programmed it," then my question is WHY do they program it this way?  Is there some reason you can't use `grep --file FILE`?
4. Is there some convention you should follow?
5. Does the leading `-` in `grep *-*-file` play an important part in something?

I'd appreciate a solid answer on this so I can understand why programmers do it this way!

Thanks!

Comment: Originally, all options were single letter: `-a -b -c`. You could combine multiple options in a single string: `-abc`. GNU(?) introduced long options to provide more mnemonic option names. A different initial character was needed to differentiate a long name `--file` from a collection of single-letter options `-file`. (I'm intentionally ignoring BSD-style long names, since this is a non-normative answer that just gives a feel for why the two styles exist).)

Comment: This may not be the reason, but the equal signs allows an option and its value to be included in a single string where whitespace separates multiple options: `--foo=bar --baz arg` could distinguish between the `--foo` option with argument `bar`, the option `--baz`, and the unrelated positional argument `arg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, the long and short options are handled by [argp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html) & [getopt_long](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node//Getopt-Long-Options.html) (from GLibc), and also by several other options handling functions (e.g. in Qt or GTK).

And the [GNU coding standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/index.html) recommend them, and also `--help` and `--version`.

Some (rarely useful) command options have only a long form (e.g. `--time-style` for GNU `ls`).

<sup>BTW, if you write some command line software for Linux which is either free software or will be distributed (perhaps sold), please accept the `--help` option: it is becoming a very common convention. I hate the few programs not following it!</sup>

Comment: Further looking into your answer - and the GNU coding standards link, it seems that it IS a convention to be followed - http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces   Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are multiple reasons:

1. System limitations: Due to the restricted memory size in early systems you had to reduce the characters used
2. Compatibility: The short hand was kept in later versions for compatibility reasons
3. Laziness: Programmers and people working on the command line don't like to type a lot
4. Readability in scripts: The long version is perfect for the readability in scripts when you don't want to switch between code and man page to figure out a list of five, six or more options

This is my own point of view after using various OSs and command lines for more than 20 years now.